# Make an angle bisector in a triangle

Tags: tkz-collection, tkz-euclide

I want to draw a bisector going from the `AB` segment in this triangle, but I do not know how I can make it so that it does not extend beyond the triangle.  Here is my work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb,tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
        \tkzLabelPoints[below,left](A)
        \tkzDefPoint(2.25,3.320718914){B}
        \tkzLabelPoints[above](B)
        \tkzDefPoint(6,0){C}
        \tkzLabelPoints[below,right](C)
        \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
        \tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
        \tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
        \tkzDefLine[bisector](A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{a}
        \tkzDrawSegment(B,a)
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the point of intersection of line segments `Ba` and `AC` by

```
\tkzInterLL(A,C)(B,a) \tkzGetPoint{b}
```

And then draw the line segment `Bb`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb,tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
        \tkzLabelPoints[below,left](A)
        \tkzDefPoint(2.25,3.320718914){B}
        \tkzLabelPoints[above](B)
        \tkzDefPoint(6,0){C}
        \tkzLabelPoints[below,right](C)
        \tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C A,C)
        \tkzDefLine[bisector](A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{a}
        \tkzInterLL(A,C)(B,a) \tkzGetPoint{b}
        \tkzLabelPoints[below](b)
        \tkzDrawSegment(B,b)
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]